# undefined method two_dimensional? barby barcodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Barby to generate EAN13 Barcodes.

I'm getting the error: `undefined method two_dimensional?' for "400000000000":String`

The code i'm using in the controller:

```
def index
  @barcode = getnumber
  @barcode_voorbeeld = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(@barcode)
  @barcode_voorbeeld.to_html
end

def getnumber
  Barcode.first.number
end
```

In the end what I want to accomplish is to get the last Barcode model and add + 1 to the number, so something like `@barcode = getnumber + "1"` and the result of this should be in this case 400000000001

thanks in advance.

Comment: where you use `two_dimensional?` method??

Comment: It's a method of Barby. [Barby two_dimensional](https://github.com/toretore/barby/blob/92c7b73e937f9f5eb804dee55deed39695c0da39/lib/barby/outputter/html_outputter.rb) on line 53.

Comment: html outputter expects a barcode, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
@number = getnumber
@barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(@number)
@barcode_voorbeeld = Barby::HtmlOutputter.new(@barcode)
@barcode_voorbeeld.to_html
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? Right now it's only code which doesn't tell much to the potential reader unless he's already familiar with the solution.